# VS2015 Extension programmatically access Advanced Save Options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

Is there a possibility to access the "Advanced Save Options" Settings (File->Advanced Save Options) programmatically from inside a Visual Studio Extension?

Clarification: We want to change the Encoding with which the file is saved and optionally the Line Settings too.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.AdvancedSaveOptions")` to trigger the dialog. If you want to do the equivalent of it, you can change text buffer settings directly but you'll need to clarify your question then.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! You are right, the question is not clear enough, i clarified it. Due to your answer i found the "Encoding" Property on "ITextdocument". Any idea about the Line Endings?